# Using vw to resize container with nested divs

Tags: html, css, resize, viewport

I am using a container `div` as a box to encapsulate some information: text and a google map embed. I want them to resize according to window size without becoming out of place. I am using `vw` but as they shrink with the window the box no longer encapsulates the information as it overflows out the side or bottom. This fiddle demonstrates what I mean.
 If you shrink the window size all the way down they are no longer encapsulating each other with the same margins.

HTML:

```
<div class="three">
 <div class="two">
  <div class="one">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.one {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background-color: #76ccde;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.two {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background-color: #c976de;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.three {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  background-color: #a7de76;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gokcLvtv/11/

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: I think what if you change the divs to be block elements when you shrink down, it will be better as a design..

Comment: Can you update your code with the data? So we could understand better `the box no longer encapsulates the information as it overflows out the side or bottom` - unless I missing something,